# Facebook duplicate symbol error in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing a difficulty where I am getting no where. My condition is I have to support iOS 9 and still have to use Xcode 6.4 (I am not ready now to upgrade to Xcode 7).

If I use **FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip**, I use

```
fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result

        }
    })
```

> Whitelisting facebook app in plist file and added keys discussed in [facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

**in iOS9**
App switches to native facebook app and does not user information back from app However I can use simulator to see my app

if I use **FacebookSDKs-iOS-20151026.zip**, I have to use

```
 fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self.presentingViewController, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result

        }
    })
```

I am getting user informations from devices from both iOS 9 and below however there is a linker error with duplicate symbol error.

The issue is I have read that, I will have to use Xcode 7 to get rid of this; however I am not ready to upgrade my app to Swift 2.0 and I have to support iOS 9 too.

Comment: There is a weird behaviour of Facebook too, if I set the loginbehaviour to Web, it opens up UIWebView and then switches to app and I get result, then the web view does not close, it also ask for username and password to login and it also does not return values!!!!

Comment: Please post the complete linker error here, chances are that you caused this by adding a framework (for example) more than once.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser will this act like this? I mean work for device and then don't work for simulator?